# How connect nhibernate to local SQLEXPRESS?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have in project simple connection to database:

```
public static string GetConnectionString()
        { 
            return @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Application.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";            
        }
```

Now I try to implement NHibernate to project.

hibernate.cfg.xml here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>        
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>    
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>  
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\1\Desktop\Application+\Application\Application.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True</property>    
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>    
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Test class "Clients" object here:

```
    public class Clients
    {
        private Guid id;
        private string name;
        private string phone;
        private string fax;
        private string email;
        private string address;
        private string contactPerson;

        public virtual Guid Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set { phone = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Fax
        {
            get { return fax; }
            set { fax = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }

        public virtual string ContactPerson
        {
            get { return contactPerson; }
            set { contactPerson = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
```

Clients.hbm.xml here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="WrapperObjects" namespace="WrapperObjects">  
  <class name="Clients" table="Clients" lazy="false">  
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="name" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="Phone" column="phone" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="Fax" column="fax" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="Email" column="email" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="Address" column="address" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="ContactPerson" column="contactPerson" type="System.String"/>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I used it like this:

```
public static void Configure()
        {            
            sessions = new Configuration().Configure().AddClass(typeof(Clients)).BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        public static void Insert(Clients pb)
        {            
            using (ISession session = sessions.OpenSession())            
            using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {                
                session.Save(pb);                
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
```

On Configure() method appears an error: Keyword not supported.Parameter name: attachdbfilename 
How fix??))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>        
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>    
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>  
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\1\Desktop\Application+\Application\Application.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True</property>    
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>    
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Notice you are using the NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver driver_class and NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect dialect, you need to change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>        
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>    
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>  
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\1\Desktop\Application+\Application\Application.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True</property>    
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property> 
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I assumed you are using MSSQL 2008, change to NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect if you are using 2005

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate?_sscc=t

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a connection string without `User Instance`
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/60889070-5c3c-4823-ae9f-1ed6e32b2ce8

example:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

source: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

To use the User Instance functionality you need to enable it on the SQL Server. This is done by executing the following command: sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'.

since the path may be absolute or relative, you can also try:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=Application.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

or

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=Application.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the MySqlDataDriver as your connection.driver_class in your NH config. Set it to NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver instead.

Likewise, set the dialect to NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect